# Dart won't get dependencies

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to teach myself Dart by using angular dart since I'm fairly familiar with angular.  I'm having some trouble though, when I use the dart editor to get my dependencies I keep getting this error

`Transformer library "package:di/module_transformer.dart" not found`

In the packages folder all I get are a bunch of empty folders where my dependencies should be.  Here is my yaml file

```
name: angular_dart_example
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular: any
  browser: any
  transformer: any
  unittest: any
transformers:
  - angular:
      html_files:
        - web/index.html
```

Tried to google search but I haven't found anything on this issue.  Please help.

Comment: Can you please try to run `pub cache repair` from the command line.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really stopping me from working.  Please post your answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pub cache repair` is always worth a try when dependencies behave weird.